# Given an integer time in the format hhmmss how can it be formatted to hh:mm:ss

Tags: c, time, timestamp

I am trying to split a timestamp in C into a suitable format, this format is to be `hh:mm:ss`.

The timestamp is stored as a positive integer in the format `hhmmss`. Is there a way to format this in C?

I have no code to show as I have no idea where to start really, my idea is store the timestamp in a character array, then every 2 characters print a `':'` character.

Example output:

```
timestamp = 123456
```

I want it shown as `12:34:56`

```
timestamp = 010203
```

I want it shown as `01:02:03`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int timestamp = 10203;
int hour = timestamp / 10000;
int minute = timestamp % 10000 / 100;
int second = timestamp % 100;

printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second);
```

Be careful when the timestamp starts with `0`, because `010203` is an octet integer literal, the result may not be what you expected.

Answer (score 3):

You can use integer division to split the number up how you like.

For example, to get the seconds you could do

```
seconds = timestamp % 100
```

And to get the minutes you could

```
minutes = (timestamp / 100) % 100
```

Then you can use `printf` to print out the time in any format you like.

e.g.

```
printf("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
```

Comment: and timestamp / 10000 for hours

Comment: Left as an exercise for the reader. I was trying to show how to do it, not actually do it.